# recreating biblatex option autocite=footnote,style=verbose-trad1 in bibtex

Tags: bibliographies

I am currently generating my bibliography as follows:

```
\usepackage[autocite=footnote,style=verbose-trad1]{biblatex}
\let\cite\autocite
```

This generates full citations in footnotes, with optional pre- and post-notes.

Depressingly, it looks like I'll have to regress to bibTeX for a journal thing, so to make things run smoothly, I'd like to put my house in order before sending off the manuscript.

So what are my options? What `\bibliographystyle` should I use so that I get full citations with the `\cite` command? Is there a way to get references as footnotes with bibtex?

Or do I have to sed-fu my way to changing my `\cite`s into `\footnote\cite`s with the pre/post notes shifted as needed?

Comment: I have not added the biblatex tag, because this doesn't seem to be a biblatex question, really.

Comment: As `biblatex` is able to use BibTex as backend, what do you mean by "regress to bibTeX"? Is using `biblatex` not admissible, but other bibliography packages (e.g., `jurabib`) are?

Comment: @lockstep I don't actually know what packages I can use (I'm trying to find out) but I _do_ know that biblatex isn't allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I see it, the tricky part is not `\let`ting `\cite` to `\footcite`, but emulating the full citation and ibidem mechanisms of `verbose-trad1`. The [jurabib](ftp://indian.cse.msu.edu/pub/mirrors/CTAN/help/Catalogue/entries/jurabib.html) package, which is not maintained anymore, seems to have served as a model for numerous `biblatex` features. Here's an example using `jurabib` that comes at least close to `verbose-trad1` (a lot of minor formatting is still missing).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[%
  citefull=first,%
  ibidem=strictdoublepage,
  authorformat=citationreversed,%
  titleformat=colonsep,%
]{jurabib}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\cite\footcite
}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\biblnfont}{\normalfont}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\bibfnfont}{\normalfont}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\bibelnfont}{\normalfont}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\bibefnfont}{\normalfont}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Bli74,
  author = {Blinder, Alan S.},
  year = {1974},
  title = {The economics of brushing teeth},
  journal = {Journal of Political Economy},
  volume = {82},
  number = {4},
  pages = {887--891},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Some text.\cite{Bli74}

Some text.\cite[p.~887]{Bli74}

\bibliographystyle{jurabib}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if this gets through. I'd forgotten about the ibidem features, so that's not important: it was part of the style demanded, but I hate it. So if it doesn't do that it's not important: if the editors want that style, they can do it themselves!