# autocite=footnote

Tags: biblatex, citing

Sir, I saw you answer a question in which you wrote that autocite was good because you could rewrite it as autocite=footnote.  Could you give an example of how you would do that?

Comment: You will probably need to be a little more specific with this.  It isn't clear what you are asking.  Maybe try to find the question that you have in mind, link to it and elaborate on what you are after.  Someone will almost certainly be able to help you, but they will need a little more information to work with.

Comment: Searching for autocite=footnote gives a number of links was it perhaps one of these? [bibliographies](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14155/14100), [back references](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43474/14100), [custom prefixes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42493/14100)

Answer (score 29):

(You are possibly referring to my [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5105/510) to [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex))

For citations that aren't used in the flow of the text ("As Einstein (1905) showed ...", produced by `\textcite`), `biblatex` offers four basic citation commands resp. package options:

- `\cite` [`autocite=plain`]: Citations are typeset as-is;
- `\parencite` [`autocite=inline`]: Citations are typeset in parentheses;
- `\footcite` [`autocite=footnote`]: Citations are typeset as footnotes;
- `\supercite` [`autocite=superscript`] (only available for the `numeric` style family): Citations are typeset as superscripts.

Instead of choosing one of those four commands, one may simply use the higer-level command `\autocite`; `biblatex` will automatically translate it into the lower-level citation command most appropriate for the style family (e.g., `\parencite` for `authoryear`, `\footcite` for `authortitle`).

If you want to switch to a non-default citation command (e.g., `\footnote` for `authoryear`), you simply add the corresponding package option:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,autocite=footnote]{biblatex}
```

Comment: what does `autocite*{}` does?

Comment: @aan In the document, it says the asterisk will be transferred to the interpreted command: if `autocite`-->`parencite`, then `autocite*`-->`parencite*`.